# If I remove my GPU drivers and don't have integrated graphics, what happens?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, integrated-graphics

I currently use [DDU](https://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html) (Display Driver Uninstaller) to remove my GPU driver before I update them. Basically, it goes like this:

Download the new driver installer from NVIDIA. Boot into safe mode. Remove current driver with DDU, restart PC. Install new driver, restart PC again to get new drivers without any problems.

I do it like this because sometimes my NVIDIA control panel disappears if I don't remove the previous drivers first. I've been looking into getting a new CPU that doesn't have integrated graphics (Not that I don't want an iGPU, just the one I'm looking at wouldn't have one). Will my PC not work correctly because there would be no iGPU to render the display inbetween the removal and updating of the drivers, or would it still render fine?

If you need to know, I have a GTX 1060 3GB, but I don't think it really matters for a question like this

Comment: If you don't have an iGPU why are drivers for that iGPU installed?  Using DDU should be unnecessary, using the clean installation option with Nvidia's installer, should be enough. If you uninstall your display drivers it fails back to the Microsoft Basic Display adapter.  NVidia's GeForce Experience is only required for drivers tweak for games, NVidia, does offer a driver that doesn't require it.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't say I don't have an iGPU, I said I'm looking into getting a new CPU, and the new CPU I'm looking at doesn't have an iGPU. About the last part you said, I edited my post to make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no drivers, your machine will start to an 'emergency' recognition form, that Windows will automatically engage. Maybe only 800x600 or so & very slow to redraw, but you *will* be able to see enough to install correct drivers.

btw, You don't have to install all of NVidia's 'Experience' [yes, it's buggy, bloated & a waste of space if you don't need what it does to try be 'helpful'].

You can always install just the drivers & regular control panel manually from https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx

Comment: This is a perfect answer, but about the last part you put, when I try to install GPU drivers (no matter where from, forgot to mention that sorry) without removing the previous drivers, the NVIDIA Control Panel disappears.

Comment: but have you tried not installing all the cra… ermm bells & whistles, ***just*** the driver/cp minimum install? The rest is technically optional, whatever NVidia might think.

Comment: yes, nothing changes. I've tried uninstalling without DDU, just the drivers, clean install, etc, nothing works.